# I'm trying to find elements of a column in a dataframe in the columns of another dataframe, but index() is not working for me

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to find the elements of the column 'Start (m)' of the corrosion dataframe in the column 'Inicio (m)' of the riesgoRel dataframe and get the indices stored in a list. I implemented the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

corrosion = pd.read_excel('Corrosion.xlsx', index=False)
TPdamage = pd.read_excel('Daños por terceros.xlsx', index=False)

for row in corrosion['Start (m)']:
    indexcorr[row]=riesgoRel['Progresiva Inicio (m)'].index(corrosion['Start (m)'][row])
    
print(indexcorr)
```

But when I try to run this, I get the following error: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable. I'm guessing there is a fairly simple mistake somewhere but I cannot figure it out.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try this:

```
final_list = corrosion[corrosion ['Start (m)']\
                      .isin(riesgoRel['Progresiva Inicio (m)'].values)]\
                      .index.tolist()
```

`final_list` is the list of all desired indices.

Answer (score 0):

change the files formats to CSV and work with pandas data frame.